# A question about the span of functions.

Tags: definition

I am having trouble understanding the span of functions, my problem is:

What is $\operatorname{span}\{a\sin(x),b\}$, and what is its dimension?

I understand this in terms of vectors, but not in terms of functions, so any enlightenment would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enlightenment: Functions *are* vectors.

Assuming you mean $a$ and $b$ are fixed constants in your base field $F$ (probably $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), then
$$
    \text{Span}_F\{a\sin x,b\} = \{f_1 a\sin x + f_2 b : f_1,f_2 \in F\}.
$$

When viewing $v = a \sin x$ and $w = b$ as *vectors*, the equation
$$
    f_1 a\sin x + f_2 b = f_1 v + f_2 w = 0
$$
means that *for all values of* $x \in F$ (or whatever the domain of $\sin x$ is assumed to be)
$$
    f_1 a\sin x + f_2 b = 0.
$$
Are there any constants $f_1$ and $f_2$ that make this true? If not, then the span has dimension $2$. If so, its dimension is less than two, since this says $v$ and $w$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: To make it true you would need $f_1,f_2\ne 0$ s.t $f_1a\sin(x)+f_2b=0,\,\forall x\in[0,1]$? (my function domian is $[0,1]$), in which case this is not true so I would believe the dimension is 2 correct?

Comment: That's correct! The dimension is in fact $2$, and for precisely the reason you mention.